# WIX invoking Batch file in InstallExecution Sequence

Tags: batch-file, wix, invoke

I am new to WIX and I am trying to invoke a batch file from my WIX installer.
MyBatch.bat contains a simple Copy of a Text file from c:\ to D:\

I am unable to invoke the batch file. Below is my code.

Please help me out.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?define ProductName='Test Product' ?>
  <?define ProductVersion='1.0.0.0' ?>
  <?define ProductCode='b7bc7c6f-9a4e-4973-be84-eca8e3427c97'?>
  <?define UpgradeCode='06a81104-1e30-463d-87e1-e8a79b4c682a'?>
  <?define Manufacturer='Respond'?>
  <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" Language="1033" Version='$(var.ProductVersion)' Name='Respond'
  Manufacturer='$(var.Manufacturer)' UpgradeCode='$(var.UpgradeCode)'>
    <Package InstallerVersion='200' Compressed='yes' />
    <Media Cabinet='media1.cab' EmbedCab='yes' Id ='1' />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder'>
        <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='$(var.ProductName)'>
          <Component Id='ProductComponent' Guid='b11556a2-e066-4393-af5c-9c9210187eb2'>
            <File Id='Calc' DiskId='1' Source='C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe'/>
            <File Id='my_batch_script' Name='MyBatch.bat' DiskId='1' Source='MyBatch.bat'   />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id='ProgramMenuFolder'>
        <Directory Id='ApplicationProgramsFolder' Name='$(var.ProductName)'>
          <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='EDED00D8-2465-46CA-86D6-B20DE921EFA6'>
            <Shortcut Id='ShortcutCalc' Description='$(var.ProductName)' Name ='Calculator of Windows'
            Target='[INSTALLLOCATION]Calc.exe' WorkingDirectory='INSTALLLOCATION'/>
            <RemoveFolder Id='ApplicationProgramsFolder' On='uninstall'/>
            <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)' Type ='multiString'
            Name='installed' Value='1' KeyPath='yes'/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Title='SetupProject1' Level='1' Id ='AppFeature'>
      <ComponentRef Id='ProductComponent' Primary='yes'/>
      <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable'/>
    </Feature>

    <Property Id='WIXUI_INSTALLDIR' Value='INSTALLDIR' ></Property>
    <WixVariable Id='WixUILicenseRtf' Overridable='yes' Value='License.rtf'/>
    <?include CustomActions.wxi?>
    <UI>
      <?include UISequence.wxi?>
      <?include Dialogs.wxi?>
    </UI>

    <CustomAction Id="BatchCmd" Property="ThePath" Value="[INSTALLDIR]MyBatch.bat" />
    <CustomAction Id="BatchRun" Property="ThePath" ExeCommand='"[INSTALLDIR]MyBatch.bat"' Return='asyncWait' Impersonate="yes"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="BatchCmd" After="InstallFiles" >Not Installed </Custom>
      <Custom Action="BatchRun" After="BatchCmd">Not Installed </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.

```
<CustomAction Id="test"
    ExeCommand="[INSTALLDIR]MyBatch.bat"
    Directory="INSTALLDIR" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="test" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: can you add the text of the bat file to your answer? Just wondering what's inside...

Comment: A good news. Any whitespaces are allowed in *INSTALLDIR* and in the `ExeCommand="[INSTALLDIR]MyBatch.bat"`. I.e. no need for the single quote trick `ExeCommand='"[INSTALLDIR]MyBatch.bat"'`

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're solving your problem with the wrong tool. If the file to copy is a part of your application, you should author a [Component](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_component.htm) with this [File](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_file.htm) inside. Otherwise, if you need just to copy some external file already present on a target system, you should author a [CopyFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm) element, nesting it under Component element.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Yan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565767/572834), you solve your task the wrong way.

---

As for batch files, they are not executed on its own like an .exe, it is `cmd.exe` which reads the bat file and executes it line by line.

To run a batch file, you should run it this way:

```
cmd.exe /c batch.bat
```

Comment: [ExeCommand="c:\test\test.BAT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563820/wix-invoking-batch-file-in-installexecution-sequence/45918334#45918334) really works

Comment: <CustomAction Id="RunBat" Directory="INSTALLDIR"
         ExeCommand='[SystemFolder]\cmd /c "test.bat"'
         Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' Return='ignore'/> 

<InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="RunBat" After="InstallFiles">
              NOT (REMOVE~="ALL")
          </Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add your CustomAction defnition as given below. Make sure that Return="ignore" if you are not returning anything from bat file.

```
<CustomAction Id="RunBat" Directory="your_directory"
    ExeCommand='"c:\test\test.BAT"'
    Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' Return='ignore'/>
```

Also in the installExecuteSequence sequence  add the action before InstallFinalize

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RunBat" Before="InstallFinalize">
        NOT (REMOVE~="ALL")
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: I want to mentions that this works with whitespaces and without single quotes too `ExeCommand="C:\0  0  0\my batch file.bat  some_param"`